# Best way to evaluate different MA/PhD programs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, undergraduate

This is connected to my post [from yesterday](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/170823/eligibility-of-pursuing-graduate-school-in-english-with-only-a-minor-in-the-subj). I'm a rising junior and an English/Philosophy double major from the United States, and I've decided to get a jump on looking into programs I might apply to a couple years from now. But I've always had trouble distinguishing between different MA/PhD programs.

How do I tell which schools are better for one area of specialization than another (I have a lot more trouble with this with English than Philosophy)? Where can I learn a particular program's strengths and weaknesses? How about basic prestige, and job prospects post-graduation—is there any meaningful distinction between, say, UCB and UChicago for an English PhD?

Sorry if this question is a little broad, but this is my first time doing this, and I'd just like to know where to start.

Comment: Does this help? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/ive-been-admitted-to-multiple-phd-programs-how-should-i-choose-between-them

Comment: @Dawn It does, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you spend a lot of time and effort on this you could be spending it more effectively.

The sort of doctoral education you get depends much more on your advisor, your relationship to them, and what you do yourself than the "ranking of the school.

MA/MS programs are a bit different in that some are pretty much classroom based and some require some sort of creative work, research in the sciences, say. Perhaps a department web site will give you guidance about that. What sort of thesis, if any, is required, say.

But note that all university rankings are an amalgam of statistical measures over several criteria. And statistical measures never apply to individuals, except in the broadest terms.

I'll focus on doctoral studies here. What you need is an advisor whose "technique" matches your needs. Some are very hands on, with a lot of suggestions and a lot of oversight. Many students need this sort of support others are smothered by it. Other advisors are very hands off, perhaps answering questions - or sending you to sources - and just leaving you to it. Some (probably fewer) students thrive in such an environment.

But great and not so great advisors are distributed through the total university universe (so to speak). Some professors at highly rated universities are so busy with their own "thing" that they have little time or effort to spare for their advisees unless they are very closely aligned. It is probably worse in some sciences where PIs sometimes don't really know their "advisees" nor interact with them much at all, leaving it to post docs to supply any guidance.

Moreover, if you are planning on applying for graduate (especially doctoral) study, apply to institutions over a fairly wide range of rankings. If you only apply to the "top ten" (whatever that might mean) you may well be entirely disappointed. It is difficult in the US to get much if any meaningful contact with a potential advisor before you are accepted and maybe not even then for a while. But the 50th ranked university in a field is still a fine place to study.

I'll also suggest that if your ultimate goal is a doctorate, that you don't bother with an MA first. Just apply to doctoral programs. Many will provide the opportunity to earn a masters along the way for little (or no) extra work. But a masters isn't even needed if your aspire to a career in academia.

And, spend some time and effort once accepted in to a place to evaluate the various professors as possible advisors. Ask around about how individuals are to work with and what their "style" is - how helpful they are. A prestigious advisor might be good - or might be so busy as to be of little help. Everything depends. Entering a doctoral program immediately from a BA will give you the time for this evaluation. It is harder if you need to choose an advisor having just arrived at a place.

If you wind up as a mediocre student at Yale, with only so-so letters of recommendation you will wind up worse than if you excel at some "lesser" place. Some true idiots and charlatans have come out of Ivy League places.

Wind up in a situation where you can brag about what you accomplished rather than the "prestige" of your institution. Find a good and compatible advisor. Work hard. Prosper.

---

Sorry I have no basis to judge particular schools, especially for English studies. Your undergraduate professors are probably a good source of information about what schools are worth looking at.

Comment: Would you consider adding some of this to the canonical question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/ive-been-admitted-to-multiple-phd-programs-how-should-i-choose-between-them

Comment: @Dawn, thanks for the idea, but my answer here (actually frame changing or at least frame expanding) is about how to think about grad schools prior to applying. I think it would be even more of a frame breaker there, where the question is about evaluating offers already made. But, there should be a canonical question on this topic. I say these things fairly often.